# what if the Kirchoff Voltage Law were wrong?

Tags: resistors

how would that affect the definition of voltage?

Comment: [MIT physics lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwIk2gew-R8) discussing limitation of Kirchoff laws.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Limitations_2) lists a limitation: *KVL is based on the assumption that there is no fluctuating magnetic field linking the closed loop. This is not a safe assumption for AC circuits.*

Comment: @JYelton But with proper treatment (Laplace), we can apply KVL to AC circuits with complex impedances.

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't. Voltage would still be the potential difference between two points.

Comment: If KVL were wrong, then voltage would no longer be a conservative field, and so the potential difference between two points would depend on the selected path between the points, making it meaningless to discuss or regard as a potential difference.  KVL is a discrete version of stating that a certain path integral around a loop in space, of a function related to the electric potential, is zero.

Comment: You've started your argument with the assumption that KVL would be wrong because voltage is different. In summary, your argument is "voltage is different because KVL is wrong because voltage is different". Voltage is a natural phenomenon, KVL describes properties of that phenomenon, if KVL is wrong then it would *not* change voltage. That's how science works.

Comment: The assumption "what if KVL were wrong" is in the question title.

Comment: Yes, *clearly*. Read the rest of the sentence you appear to be responding to.